# Getting undefined from jquery find() in my example

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page like this :

I have put an event on `input.global_filter` using jquery as follows:

```js
$('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function() {
  document.write($(this).find('.example:first').prop('tagName'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Table3-->
<table class="example" data-column="3">
  ......
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="global_filter">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Table1-->
<table class="example" data-column="1">
  ......
</table>

<!-- Table2-->
<table class="example" data-column="2">
  ......
</table>
```

This results in `undefined`. It should give the result `TABLE`. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Because the `<input>` does not have any children (or descendants) for you to `.find`

Comment: Then what should be the way to get it ? Can you please help me with it

Comment: Remove the `.find` and use plain jQuery selection instead with `$(`

Comment: you are trying to find inside $(this) object which does not have any child, so yo have to use $(document).find()

Comment: Yes i understand , but I want the table which is just closest to it to be selected. If I use $(document).find(), it will search the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use `parents` instead of `find`. Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function() {
    console.log($(this).parents().siblings('table').first().prop('tagName'));
    console.log($(this).parents().next('.example').data('column'));
  });
})
```

Comment: No this will not work as closest() traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. I want the table just next down to it.

Comment: @MazharMIK, you have use siblings table

Comment: I want the table just next to it downwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are using `$(this)` and when event get trigger `this` become the input field it means `this`  keyword referring to input field, And then you are trying to find `example:first` inside the input field so you are getting undefined.

Check the following solution

```
document.write($('body').find('.example:first').prop('tagName'));
```

Comment: I got your point. But look at the question now, I have made a small change. ('body') will make it to search from to top and what if there is another table (as mentioned in my question) in the top. My main motive is to access the table just next to it.

Comment: Okay check this   `$(this).closest("Table").prop('tagName')` . Is this you are asking for ??

Comment: No this will not work as closest()  traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. I want the table just next down to it.

Comment: I have mentioned the table names now. I want to access the next table (Table2).

Answer (score 0):

please try with this:

```
   $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function() {
      document.write($('.example').eq(1).prop('tagName'));
    });
```

Comment: No it will access the Table3. I want to access Table2